# ChoicesJS how to append programatically options?

Tags: javascript, html, choicesjs

How to append options to an existing initialized ChoicesJS instance?

Given the following HTML:

```
<select id="random-select"></select>

<button onclick="append()">
  Append new data do select
</button>
```

And the following JS:

```
// initializes the plugin
function init()
{
    const data = 
    {
        removeItemButton: true,
        duplicateItemsAllowed: false,
        searchEnabled: true,
        searchChoices: true,
    };
    
    const el = document.getElementById('random-select');
  
    new Choices(el, data);
}

function append()
{
    // How to append to existing element already initialized?
    const el = document.getElementById('random-select');
  
    // DOESN'T WORK
    el.setChoices([{ value: 1, label: 'test' }]);
    
     // DOESN'T WORK
    el.choices.setValue([{ value: 1, label: 'test' }]);
}
```

Both `el.setChoices` and `el.choices.setValue` give an error:

> setChoices is not a function

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setValue')"

Check the **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lar2qbtg/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code documentation on GitHub, [`setChoices`](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/tree/v10.2.0?tab=readme-ov-file#setchoiceschoices-value-label-replacechoices) is an instance method of the `Choices` class, so you'd need to invoke it as such.

```js
const choicesInstance = new Choices(/* ... */);
choicesInstance.setChoices(/* ... */);
```

Here's an example based on the documentation and the code you provided:

```js
const choices = new Choices(
  document.getElementById("random-select"),
  {
    // allowHTML: true, // uncomment to suppress warning message
    removeItemButton: true,
    duplicateItemsAllowed: false,
    searchEnabled: true,
    searchChoices: true,
  },
);

const append = () => choices.setChoices([{ value: 1, label: "test" }]);

document.getElementById("append-choices").addEventListener("click", append);
```

```html
<!-- Include Choices CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@10.2.0/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css" />
<!-- Include Choices JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/choices.js@10.2.0/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>

<select id="random-select"></select>
<button id="append-choices">Append new data do select</button>
```

Comment: If you invoke like `new Choices(...)` it will trigger an error sayign that the element already is attached to a `Choices` instance / something similar.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549885/choicesjs-how-to-append-programatically-options/77550096?noredirect=1#comment136716028_77550096) @Linesofcode That's right — don't create the class instance more than once: just keep a reference to it and re-use it (as shown in the code in this answer).

Comment: That would work if I didn't have dynamic instances....and could only use a constant variable. Unfortunatelly is not the case, I'll probably end up using some sort of array to handle this. I'll mark your answer as solution though.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549885/choicesjs-how-to-append-programatically-options/77550096?noredirect=1#comment136716100_77550096) @Linesofcode You can use a [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) of `element -> class instance` if you need to keep dynamic associations while still allowing for garbage collection.